# How can I connect elements from 2 lists and show them in ListView?

Tags: flutter, dart

First is list of DateTime, the second list items are Reservations.

**Then represent it like in the image bellow.**

[Image representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKZkG.png)

This is the loop where I search and create the view. Variable matchingReservation when null shows empty space.

```
Consumer<List<Reservation>>(
                builder: (context, snapshot, _) {
                  var reservedTimes = snapshot.where((element) =>
                      isSameDay(element.dateTimeStart, _selectedDay));
                  final startTime = DateTime(_selectedDay.year,
                      _selectedDay.month, _selectedDay.day, 8, 0);

                  return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: 29,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        final time =
                            startTime.add(Duration(minutes: 30 * index));

                        final matchingReservation =
                            reservedTimes.firstWhereOrNull(
                                (element) => isReservationTime(time, element));

                        return customListTile(time, matchingReservation);
                      });
                },
              ),
```

This is a check if time fits into reservation time

```
    return (time.isAtSameMomentAs(reservation.dateTimeStart) ||
            time.isAfter(reservation.dateTimeStart)) &&
        time.isBefore(reservation.dateTimeEnd);
  }
```

Comment: I think it's a bit unclear what you are asking. It seems you have a Reservation object with start and end times, and then a start and end time for a day, but I'm not sure what you want to end up with. Can you describe in a bit more detail exactly what the output you are want will look like?

Comment: @anqit I modified my question. I hope you'll understand it better